# Slow ORDER BY in large table

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

I have problem with ORDER BY clause. When I remove ORDER BY in following query, query is finished in 0.004 seconds.
If I keep it, query is running very slow = 56 seconds.
It is because MySQL is first grabbing all 500 000 records, then sorting and finally returing only first 18 records.

How can I solve this big table ordering problem ?

Thanks.

Explain:
http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/9440/explain.png

SQL Query:

```
    SELECT `_sd`.`sazbaDPHId`, `_sd`.`sazbaDPH`, `_sd`.`sazbaDPHProcent`, `_zk`.`zboziKategorieId`, `_zk`.`zboziId`, 
    `_zk`.`kategorieId`, `_zk`.`zboziKategoriePoradi`, `_k`.`kategorieId`, `_k`.`kategorieNazev`, `_k`.`kategorieCelyNazev`,
     `_k`.`kategorieKod`, `_k`.`kategorieCesta`, `_k`.`kategoriePopis`, `_k`.`kategorieKeywords`, `_k`.`kategorieRodiceId`, `_k`.`kategoriePoradi`, `_k`.`kategorieSkryta`, `_k`.`kategorieVTopMenu`, `_v`.`vyrobceId`, `_v`.`vyrobceNazev`, `_v`.`vyrobceKod`,
     `_v`.`vyrobceKoeficient`, `_tzvz`.`typZboziVlastnostZboziId`, `_tzvz`.`typZboziId`, `_tzvz`.`vlastnostZboziId`,
     `_vzh`.`vlastnostZboziHodnotaId`, `_vzh`.`zboziId`, `_vzh`.`vlastnostZboziId`, `_vzh`.`vlastnostZboziHodnota`, `zvc`.`zboziVyslCenaId` AS`zvc_zboziVyslCenaId`, `zvc`.`zboziVyslCenaZboziId` AS`zvc_zboziVyslCenaZboziId`, `zvc`.`vyslCena` AS`zvc_vyslCena`,
     `zvc`.`vyslCenaSDPH` AS`zvc_vyslCenaSDPH`, `this`.`zboziId`, `this`.`zboziNazev`, `this`.`zboziKod`, `this`.`zboziIdentifikator`,
     `this`.`zboziPartNum`, `this`.`zboziEAN`, `this`.`zboziPopis`, `this`.`zboziOstatniParametry`, `this`.`zboziInterniInfo`,
     `this`.`zboziProdejniCena`, `this`.`zboziAkcniCena`, `this`.`zboziSetovaCena`, `this`.`zboziMocCena`, `this`.`sazbaDPHId`,
     `this`.`vyrobceId`, `this`.`typZboziId`, `this`.`stavZboziId`, `this`.`skladovaDostupnostId`, `this`.`zdrojCenId`, `this`.`zboziPHE`,
     `this`.`zboziAutorskyPoplatek`, `this`.`zboziVahovyPoplatek`, `this`.`nemenitStavZbozi` 
    FROM `tbl_Zbozi`AS this 
    LEFT JOIN `reg_SazbaDPH`AS _sd ON this.sazbaDPHId = _sd.sazbaDPHId 
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_Zbozi_Kategorie`AS _zk ON this.zboziId = _zk.zboziId 
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_Kategorie`AS _k ON _zk.kategorieId = _k.kategorieId 
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_Vyrobce`AS _v ON this.vyrobceId = _v.vyrobceId 
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_TypZbozi_VlastnostZbozi`AS _tzvz ON this.typZboziId = _tzvz.typZboziId 
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_VlastnostZboziHodnota`AS _vzh ON this.zboziId = _vzh.zboziId AND _vzh.vlastnostZboziId = _tzvz.vlastnostZboziId 
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_Zbozi_VyslCena`AS zvc ON this.zboziId = zvc.zboziVyslCenaZboziId 
    WHERE _k.kategorieId IN (155317, 5570, 155445, 5706, 5707, 155429, 155430, 155431, 5708, 5709, 5710, 155427, 155426, 155428, 11413, 5713,
     5714, 5715, 5716, 5717, 5718, 5719, 5720, 10245, 10253, 11253, 10834, 10269, 10249, 10246, 10247, 10248, 5723, 5725, 5726, 5727, 5728, 5729,         
     155319, 5815, 5816, 5817, 5818, 5819, 5822, 5824, 5832, 11406, 11411, 11410, 11409, 
     6069, 6070, 6072, 6073, 6075, 6078, 6086, 11414, 6185, 155433, 6186, 6187, 6188, 6190, 6191, 6193, 6198, 6199, 6200, 6201, 6202, 6203, 6207,
     6209, 11442, 6210, 6211, 6212, 6215, 6216, 6217, 6218, 6219, 6220, 155366, 6221, 11339, 11340, 11341, 11359, 6222, 6223, 6224, 6225, 6226,
     6227, 6228, 11099, 155376, 6231, 6232, 6233, 6234, 6235, 6236, 155391, 155392, 155437, 6237, 6238, 6241, 6243, 6244, 6245, 6246, 6247, 6248,
     6249, 6250, 6251, 6252, 6253, 6254, 6256, 6257, 6258, 6259, 6260, 6261, 10839, 155362, 6262, 6263, 6264, 6265, 155361, 6267, 6269, 11390,
     11346, 11112, 11394, 11397, 155393, 6270, 11436, 10292, 6271, 6272, 6275, 6277, 6278, 6279, 6280, 6281, 11348, 10288, 11113, 6283, 6284,
     6285, 6287, 155494, 11114, 6292, 6293, 6294, 6295, 6296, 6297, 6298, 6300, 6301, 6302, 6303, 6304, 11116, 6305, 10781, 6306, 6307, 6308,
     6309, 6310, 6311, 6313, 6314, 6315, 6316, 6317, 6318, 6327, 6328, 155451, 6333, 6334, 6335, 6337, 6340, 6342, 6343, 6344, 6345, 6346, 11344,
     11389, 10289, 10291, 10302, 10303, 10304, 10294, 10306, 10300, 10305, 10293, 10299, 10298, 10290, 10296, 10297, 11454, 11100, 11101,
     11117, 131475, 11402, 5680, 5684, 5685, 5686, 5687, 5688, 5689, 11383, 5702, 5703, 5704, 5705) 
AND stavZboziId IN (2)
AND zvc.zboziVyslCenaSkupinaId = '8'
ORDER BY _k.kategoriePoradi ASC LIMIT 18
```

Comment: Paste output of EXPLAIN for your query.

Comment: I attached explain results screenshot

Comment: I don't know what the equivalent is in MySQL. but in MSSQL you can get it to spit out a query plan that breaks the query down into smaller parts and describes what operations and overall impact each part will have.  Looking at something like that is better than hit or miss changes when trying to optimize a query.

Comment: The original query isn't taking a total of 0.004 seconds, it's just that MySQL knows where to start at that point.  Once you get the results, navigate to the end of the result set to force MySQL to actually load everything.

Comment: seems there is only one solution - memcached...

Comment: interesting, I removed "AND zvc.zboziVyslCenaSkupinaId = '8'"
and query is running very fast 0.02s !
Why ??

Comment: @Michal - If you get such a speed improvement and it is not obvious why, then you really need to profile what the query is doing in the background.

Comment: Without that condition, MySQL is not using filesort anymore.
Here look at new explain:
http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/8083/explainnew.png

Comment: Can anyone explain me why there is no filesort now ?
Why it is using index for ordering now ?

Answer (score 3):

How else could it work?  If it applied the order after selecting the 18 records you would get the top 18 records in the default order, which it would then sort.

You might get better performance by inserting all the values in your `IN` statement into a temp table and then joining to the temp table.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I tried it, but it only reduced time to 45 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

it still has to sort 500,000 records to find your 18 so it will be alot slower, you can speed it up by adding indexes to your kategoriePoradi column in your tables

Comment: Thanks Dave, I added BTREE index to kategoriePoradi, but I didnt get any performance.

However I have indexes on all WHERE/JOIN columns.