# mysql slow select order by on a large table

Tags: mysql, performance, select, sql-order-by

I have a large table stored in mysql (basically, a log) that looks like this:

```
  CREATE TABLE `log` (
    `ID_1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `ID_2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `DELTA` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `ACTIVE` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `DATA` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

No index. Data is inserted at random moments with random data and it work fine. Then, the table is taken offline (no read/write operations on it). The table size in this moment is around 180M records. I am adding an index on ID_1, ID_2, DELTA, ACTIVE fields (all 4, ascending). It works fairly fast (3-4 minutes).

Now, I am trying to get all the data from the table in ascending order by ID_1, ID_2, DELTA, ACTIVE (same fields and in the same order as in index) but the select stays for ages in 'SORTING RESULT' (in SHOW PROCESSLIST) until first row is returned. I tried to hint/force the SELECT statement to use the index (i.e. FORCE INDEX / USE INDEX) but there isn't any difference. Any hint on how can I increase the response speed of this kind of query:

```
SELECT `ID_1`, `ID_2`, `DELTA`, `ACTIVE` FROM `log` ORDER BY `ID_1`, `ID_2`, `DELTA`, `ACTIVE` ASC;
```

?

A similar question has been asked here: [Slow ORDER BY in large table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228603/slow-order-by-in-large-table) - but without an answer. Thought it's a good idea to post one like it, maybe someone knows the answer by now.

Thank you!

Comment: try bumping up MySQL's key_buffer_size - the default is 128k, but that's way to small for this type of usage. Up to 25% of available memory is sometimes recommended - see http://optimmysql.blogspot.com/2008/03/variable-day-out-2-keybuffersize.html

Comment: I have the same problem. @dcg, did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To efficiently sort the data, you must add a compound index using all the columns you want to use in the `ORDER BY` clause. The order of the columns in the index must be the same as the order of the columns in the `ORDER BY` clause.

In your case, it would be:

```
ALTER TABLE `log` ADD INDEX mySortIndex(`ID_1`, `ID_2`, `DELTA`, `ACTIVE`);
```

To check how MySQL is executing your query, use:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT `ID_1`, `ID_2`, `DELTA`, `ACTIVE` FROM `log` ORDER BY `ID_1`, `ID_2`, `DELTA`, `ACTIVE` ASC;
```

The output will tell you which indexes are used.

If you are only going to need a known number of result rows, you may use `LIMIT` to prevent MySQL from sorting the entire table:

```
SELECT `ID_1`, `ID_2`, `DELTA`, `ACTIVE`
FROM `log` ORDER BY `ID_1`, `ID_2`, `DELTA`, `ACTIVE` ASC
LIMIT 100;
```